# How to make a prompt box input invoke a function?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, prompt

How do I get rid of the button onclick="clickMe()" and just have the input from the prompt box execute the function?
I need the input from a prompt box to invoke the if statement, i think?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script>
   function clickMe(){
var valueInput=prompt("Please input weekday, weekend?");
var weekdayElement = document.getElementById("weekday"); 
var weekendElement = document.getElementById("weekend"); 
    if (valueInput=="weekday"){
weekdayElement.style.height = "200px"; 
weekdayElement.style.width = "250px"; 
weekdayElement.style.fontSize = "15px"; 
weekdayElement.style.color="blue";  
    if (valueInput=="weekend"){
weekendElement.style.height = "200px"; 
weekendElement.style.width = "250px"; 
weekendElement.style.fontSize = "15px"; 
weekendElement.style.color="blue";  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is an example on DOM</h1>
<div id="weekday">
    weekdays
    <p>Monday</p>
    <p>Tuesday</p>
    <p>Wednesday</p>
    <p>Thursday</p>
    <p>Friday</p>
</div>
<div id="weekend">
    weekends
    <p>Saturday</p>
    <p>Sunday</p>
</div> 
<p><button onclick="clickMe()">Try it</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `clickMe` triggers the prompts box, but you're asking how to make the prompt box trigger `clickMe`. That's like asking the prompt box to go back in time and trigger itself. You might want to rethink your question and try to state it more clearly.

Comment: Can you clarify a little more? Currently, this code is set up to do: (1) click the button, (2) the `clickMe()` function runs, and a prompt is shown. (2) After the input is collected, the rest of the code runs. Do you want the prompt to automatically run, or are you not seeing the prescribed behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the prompt to jump when the page is loaded, and then execute the code in "clickMe" (without the prompt) once the user has input a value?
In that case, you need to run the prompt after the page has loaded. You can see an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7a6e9r2f/1/

Note that jsfiddle automatically calls the javascript code at the bottom after the page has been loaded. In your case, you need to add

```
<body onload="onLoaded()">
```

to your html so that the onLoaded function is called.